# Variable within regex statement doesn't find any matches

Tags: python, regex

When i try to find any matches with the following code, it doesn't work as i want.
I'm comparing two lists (domains and Whitelist domains) in order to find domains in my whitelist.
I've tested with some prints and strings within a variable and I've got diferent results. What's wrong in the first code?

Whitelist.txt contains the following domains:

```
.example.com
.google.com
.amazon.com
.test.com
```

Domains.txt contains the following domains:

```
subdomain.example.com
coogle.es
tested.com
bubble.googlees.com
```

Domain selected: subdomain.example.com

I've tested this code (Don't work)

```
Whitelist = 'WhitelistDominios.txt'
w = open(Whitelist,"r")
whitelines = w.readlines()
Domains = 'Domains.txt'
f = open(Domains,"r")
lines1 = f.readlines()
for line in lines1: #List with domains to search (sudomain plus domain)
     for wline in whitelines: #list with all whitelist domains (whitelist domain with the format '.domain')
         regex = wline
         regex = regex.replace('.','\.') # to escape wildcard '.'
         regex = regex.replace('\n','') # replace \n for joining metacharacter $ at the end of each string
         if re.search(regex + '$', line) != None:
             print "This domain belongs to us- " + line
```

Output1 (printing regex variable):

```
 \.example\.com
 \.google\.com
 \.amazon\.com
 \.test\.com
```

Also, i've tested with this code (works well)

```
regex = "\.example\.com"
if re.search(regex + '$', line) != None:
    print "This domain belongs to us- " + line
```

Output2 (printing regex variable):

```
 \.example\.com
 This domain belongs to us- subdomain.example.com
```

When i printed both cases I got these results:

1. A list of domains where .example.com are included with the following format: ".example.com" (\ are before .)
2. Only one string with the following format: ".example.com" (The same)

Both codes have different results and i've expected the second one but i could't find the reason of my problem.

Comment: hi, sample input code for the first one might help understand the question better.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Btw, what does this line do `regex = regex.replace('.','.')` ?

Comment: Also, this `.example.com$` is being passed to the engine. It should probably be this `\.example\.com$` as the dot `.` is a regex metachar (wildcard) that matches most every character except newlines.

Comment: Also, it's always a good idea to name variables in their type context. So, if its a regex string, name it stRx, as opposed to a regex object which can be named like Rx.

Comment: Also, a quicker way is to bail out of the current loop and go to the outter loop when you've found a match. But, I don't know python fully to know how to do that. The absolute best way is that if the whitelist is static, just make a regex out of it by joining each item with the alternation. Then join the domain list with a space. Then run  a findall type thing with  the whitelist regex on the domain string. One regex function call and you get the entire list of domains in the whitelist.

Comment: I've edited this sentence (missed argument and now edited) regex = regex.replace('.','\.') # this sentence escape the wildcard '.'

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answers, i try to explain better the code. In the first code both list are recovered from 2 text files (whitelist domains and domains to check). both list are previosly opened and works fine.

Comment: I am not sure how do you load the `lines1` and `whitelines`, but if `wline` end with '\n', I guess the `line` maybe ends with '\n' too?

Comment: Good point @Cologler , i've edited the code with more info

Comment: If you work on windows, `.readlines()` return strings ends with `\r` (not `\n`). Try to replace `.readlines()` to `.read().splitlines()`.

Comment: I work with Ubuntu, should i replace as well with that? @Cologler

Comment: You can give it a try

Comment: It doesn't work :-( , thx anyway @Cologler

Comment: @sln could you give me an example of your last comment?

Comment: Just give us an example input.. It's not hard and will get you help a lot faster..

Comment: @Akaisteph7 edited with outputs and files content

Comment: Any ideas? i'm trying to create two list with domains extracted from both files, i think it could be the format in readline() function...

Comment: @CrackenGreyjoy I ran your code and it worked fine on my system and output `\.example\.com
This domain belongs to us- subdomain.example.com` since it's the only match. Are you sure your code is the same as what is up there?

Comment: Hi @Akaisteph7, i found the problem, i miss some chars into the code ¬¬ Now the code works. Thank you very much for everyone